# COUNTNULL() as a MySQL function. How would it operate?

Tags: mysql

I am sure it would be an aggregate function because it is going to count a collection of data.

However, how does any COUNT() function operate in MySQL to perform its respective actions?

Comment: Your question isnt clear, You want invent that function?

Comment: Yes. I want to invent the function. So, assume I invent it, how would it operate? Would it operate like other functions such as COUNT(*)?

Comment: I don't see any good reason why such a function would be needed. If you create such a function, any SQL statement that uses that function will not be portable to other systems. It's possible to achieve the same result using  functions that are already available.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear what you are looking for, but for selecting a count of null values in a column, I use something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN columnname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM tablename;
```

When the value is NULL, it is assigned the value 1 otherwise 0, then summed over whatever aggregate you need.

Comment: There's one small difference between `SUM` and `COUNT`, the corner case when no rows satisfy the predicates. That is, for the query in this answer... when there are no rows in table `tablename` . The `SUM()` aggregate will return `NULL`, a `COUNT()` aggregate will return `0`.

Comment: I want to invest a COUNTNULL() function, and I think it is going to be an aggregate function. Am I correct in assuming this, since other functions that also count collections of data are aggregate functions?

Comment: @BIG_MAC_AND_FRIES You dont need invent a new funciton. Just need use `COUNT(*)` but with the right settings

Comment: @spencer7593 you are correct, I didn't consider the empty table.  Upvoting your answer.

Comment: @BrianC:  you can get the same behavior using the `SUM()` function.  Just wrap it in an `IFNULL()` function to return 0 when it's null. e.g. `SELECT IFNULL(SUM(expr),0) AS mycount FROM ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNT(*)` is an aggregate function.  In the SELECT list, the expression `COUNT(*)` will return a count of rows. Without a `GROUP BY` clause, all rows will be collapsed into a single row, and the `COUNT(*)` aggregate will contain a non-negative integer value representing the number of rows that were collapsed... a "count" of the number of rows.

As you seem to be aware, other expressions involving the `COUNT()` aggregate operate a little differently, with respect to `NULL` values.

In the SELECT list, an expression `COUNT(expr)` operates exactly like `COUNT(*)` *except* for rows with values of `expr` that evaluate to `NULL` are *not* included in the count.

This all operates according to the specification.

As far as the non-existent `COUNTNULL()` function, it depends what you want that to achieve. If you wanted to get a count of the rows that had a NULL value for an expression, you could perform a conditional test, and return a non-NULL value, and use the existing `COUNT` aggregate, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN expr IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `COUNTNULL`
  FROM ...
```

Comment: So it would indeed be an aggregate function correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember where I learned this technique, but arguably the most elegant -- or at least minimalistic -- way to invert the logic of `COUNT()` is with this expression, which admittedly gives a first impression that black magic may somehow be involved... but it's perfectly legitimate:

```
COUNT(column1 IS NULL OR NULL)
```

...this correctly counts only the rows where column1 is null, because it is equivalent to the following expression...

```
COUNT( (column1 IS NULL) OR (NULL) )
```

It's a boolean expression that can only ever evaluate to 1 ("true," when column1 is null, and this row is thus counted), or NULL (otherwise, so the row will not be counted).

Logically, it's equivalent to the `CASE` expression offered by @spencer7593.